# Android - Adding TextViews to a ListView Dynamically

Tags: android, listview, textview

So i am trying to add TextView's into my main ListView within JAVA, 
And i am encountering some problems...

instead of giving me the Value of the TextView, all i get is some random rubbish like:

```
 android.Widget.TextView@somerandomnumbersandtext
```

I am adding the textview like this:

```
        adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listItems);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    TextView tv = new TextView(SpellCast.this);
    TextView tvC = new TextView(SpellCast.this);
    tv.setText(name[i]);
    tvC.setText(Integer.toString(current[i]));
    tvC.setId(i);
    tv.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
    tvC.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
    listItems.add(tv + "");
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Why isn't this working??

thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be adding a string and not a textview.

When you call `adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>` you are saying "I'm defining a new ArrayAdapter that will contain items of the type 'String' "

So, when you try to add an item to your listview it is expecting a string. When you add a textview it is simply performing a `toString()` on the textview which is why you get that funky text.

Instead, add your text directly to the listview by calling

```
listItems.add(name[i]);
```

Comment: but i need it to have an ID so later on i can change that field in particular!

Comment: Each row in an adapter has a unique ID (generally its position). You can get this by calling long id = adapter.getItemId(position);

Comment: Thanks! how can i add subtext like this?

Comment: Using the generic implementation of ArrayAdapter it's not possible. ArrayAdapter only allows you to set 1 field. You'd need to implement your own custom Adapter at this point

Comment: Here's a pretty good example of how to make a custom adapter http://android.vexedlogic.com/2011/04/02/android-lists-listactivity-and-listview-ii-%E2%80%93-custom-adapter-and-list-item-view/